# Using while loops to approximate the taylor series of acsc

Tags: matlab, while-loop, taylor-series

I'm trying to approximate acsc using a while loop without much success, currently, the compiler is giving me the error that 'Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.' With an error at line 9. Any help is appreciated.

````
acsc_appr2 = [];
for j = 1:length(x_array)
    x = x_array(j);
    i = 1;
    k(1) = 0;
    acsc_appr2 (1) =inf; 
    while acsc_appr2 (i) >= 1e-6
        acsc_appr2 (i) = acsc_appr2 (i-1) + ...
                        (factorial(2*k)/((2^(2*k)*factorial(k)^2)))*...
                        (1./((2*k+1)*(x.^(2*k+1))));
        k = k+1;
        i = i+1;
    end
end
figure(1);
plot(x_array, acsc(x_array),'-k', 'LineWidth', 2);
hold on
plot(x_array, acsc_appr2,'--r');
hold off
xlabel('x'), ylabel('y');
legend('acsc','acsc approximation', 'location', 'northeast');
title('Q4b id:30012521');
set(gcf,'Position', get(gcf,'Position') + [0,0,150,0]);
pos1 = get(gcf,'Position');
set(gcf,'Position', pos1 - [pos1(3)/2,0,0,0]);```
````

Comment: You haven't given us values for `x_array`, so we can't run your code, but [`dbstop if error`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#buzezti-1) is your friend.

Comment: On the first iteration when i=1 you try to access acsc_appr2(i-1) which yields a 0 index.